How to create a shareable Supbase server client
I have a nextjs app that uses supabase as a database and authentication. I'm using 2 ways to instantiate the server side supabase client following these docs https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/server-side/nextjs?queryGroups=router&router=pages

Requests coming to pages/api using  `

import { createServerClient, type CookieOptions, serialize } from '@supabase/ssr'
import { type NextApiRequest, type NextApiResponse } from 'next'

export default function createClient(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const supabase = createServerClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!,
    {
      cookies: {
        get(name: string) {
          return req.cookies[name]
        },
        set(name: string, value: string, options: CookieOptions) {
          res.appendHeader('Set-Cookie', serialize(name, value, options))
        },
        remove(name: string, options: CookieOptions) {
          res.appendHeader('Set-Cookie', serialize(name, '', options))
        },
      },
    }
  )

  return supabase
}


Requests being made by my nextjs actions using:

import { createServerClient, type CookieOptions } from '@supabase/ssr';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

export const createClient = () => {
  const cookieStore = cookies();

  return createServerClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!,
    {
      cookies: {
        get(name: string) {
          return cookieStore.get(name)?.value;
        },
        set(name: string, value: string, options: CookieOptions) {
          try {
            cookieStore.set({ name, value, ...options });
          } catch (error) {
            // The `set` method was called from a Server Component.
            // This can be ignored if you have middleware refreshing
            // user sessions.
          }
        },
        remove(name: string, options: CookieOptions) {
          try {
            cookieStore.set({ name, value: '', ...options });
          } catch (error) {
            // The `delete` method was called from a Server Component.
            // This can be ignored if you have middleware refreshing
            // user sessions.
          }
        },
      },
    }
  );
};

I'm currently creating a client everytime I'm having an interaction with my database within my controllers. i.e
const handleGetResource = () => {
   const supabase =  createClient();
   const { data: resources, error } = await supabase
    .from('resources')
    .select()
    .eq('user_id', userId);
  return resources
}

This feels quite weird as I find myself doing this a lot so ideally I want to create the client once at the top of the application (when it first start up perhaps in nextconfig) and then use it throught the backand of my app. I do know that createServerClient returns a singlton however I do not know how to make it shareable across the backend files of my application.
